# AMD FirePro 2270 detected as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" -- how to get it to detect properly?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

Box: Dell XPS i7, Win 7 Ultimate.

Main video: AMD Radeon HD 7500 driving 1600x2560 display. Works great. Current v15.2 AMD driver.

For secondary displays: Brand new AMD FirePro 2270.

I have confirmed that the 2270 is supported by the current AMD drivers.

But no matter what I do, Windows sees the 2270 as a "Standard VGA" adapter. Have tried:

- rebooting mult times
- uninstalling driver for Standard VGA (to make it redetect)
- updated AMD drivers (was on 14.x, updated to 15.2)

What next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is: Install the firepro drivers from CDROM -- yes, even though the current ATI drivers are present from the 7500. (Not positive, because I ripped out the rig and did a diff setup, but that seems to be the lesson from the new setup.)